# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to dfareporting.ads.insert failed with error: Invalid value at 'profile_id' (TYPE_INT64)

Tags: google-apps-script, double-click-advertising, google-apps-script-api

I try to call this API with the following `ad` object.

```
  var ad = DoubleClickCampaigns.Ads.insert(6485800,
    {
      
      "campaignId": parseInt(singlePlacementArray[0]),
      "advertiserId": parseInt(inputSheet.getRange("J9").getValue()),
      
      //"accountId": inputSheet.getRange("H9").getValue(),
      "name": singlePlacementArray[1],
       "active": true,
       "archived": false,
      "type": "AD_SERVING_TRACKING",
      "startDate": Utilities.formatDate(singlePlacementArray[5], ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
      "endDate": Utilities.formatDate(singlePlacementArray[6], ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
      "placementAssignments": [
        {
          "placementId": parseInt(singlePlacementArray[9]),
          "active": true,
          //"sslRequired": false,
        }
      ]
    });
```

I get this error, even thought the `profile_id` is an int.

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to dfareporting.ads.insert failed with error: Invalid value at 'profile_id' (TYPE_INT64), "endDate,2023-06-30,placementAssignments,[Ljava.lang.Object;@7ad1fc95,campaignId,2.2529571E7,type,AD_SERVING_TRACKING,active,true,startDate,2021-05-29,advertiserId,6334010.0,name,video campaign test parallel tracking_cn+Video,archived,false"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the arguments of the method of `DoubleClickCampaigns.Ads.insert` is `DoubleClickCampaigns.Ads.insert(object, profileId)`. I thought that the reason of your issue might be due to this. And also, it seems that `profileId` is `string (int64 format)`. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var ad = DoubleClickCampaigns.Ads.insert({
  "campaignId": parseInt(singlePlacementArray[0]),
  "advertiserId": parseInt(inputSheet.getRange("J9").getValue()),
  //"accountId": inputSheet.getRange("H9").getValue(),
  "name": singlePlacementArray[1],
  "active": true,
  "archived": false,
  "type": "AD_SERVING_TRACKING",
  "startDate": Utilities.formatDate(singlePlacementArray[5], ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
  "endDate": Utilities.formatDate(singlePlacementArray[6], ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
  "placementAssignments": [
    {
      "placementId": parseInt(singlePlacementArray[9]),
      "active": true,
      //"sslRequired": false,
    }
  ]
}, "6485800");
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your values in the object of the 1st argument and the value of `profileId` of the 2nd argument are valid values. Please be careful this.
- From [the official document](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.4/ads#Ad), I'm not sure whether `startDate` and `endDate` can be used in this request. Are those `startTime` and `endTime`? If an error occurs for this, please check it again.

#### References:

- [Method: ads.insert](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.4/ads/insert)
- [REST Resource: ads](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.4/ads#Ad)

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know the profileId is the second arg?
The doc says:`The request body contains an instance of Ad.`

Comment: @Elad Benda Thank you for replying. About your question of `how do you know the profileId is the second arg?`, in this case, you can see it at the auto-completion of the script editor like `insert(resource: Dfareporting_v3_4.Dfareporting.V3_4.Schema.Ad, profileId: string)`.

Comment: I changed and I now get an unexplained error: `Unexpected error while getting the method or property insert on object Apiary.dfareporting.ads.` Any idea how to make it clearer?

Comment: @Elad Benda Thank you for replying. About your new issue, although I think that it is due to the object of 1st argument, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail of it from your error message. I apologize for this. In this case, I would like to propose to post it as new question. Because my answer is for your 1st question. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your all questions. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.